# Python - smtplib - Save as draft - Gmail

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

I have the following working code to send the message from GMail account:

```
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.login(FROM_EMAIL, PASSWORD)
mailServer.sendmail(FROM_EMAIL, finalReciepients, msg.as_string())
mailServer.close()    # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
```

Instead of sending the message, I want to save it in drafts folder. How can I achieve that?

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519135/creating-a-draft-message-in-gmail-using-the-imaplib-in-python) a question the uses imaplib instead of smtplib, maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 4):

SMTP is strictly for *sending* mail. If you want to *store* mail instead (as one would with a draft) then you need to use a local store or IMAP instead.